# Actionbar in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

Is possible to use own actionbar in Fragment? This means that it should not be part of Activity, but a part of fragment. If yes, please show example! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fragment can contribute items to the activity's action bar. It cannot have its own action bar. You are welcome to add something to your fragment's UI instead.